# Shouldn't these two tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

Is there any difference between tag [flags](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags) and tag [vexillology](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vexillology)? If not, shouldn't they be synonyms?

Comment: Just a side-note: your zeal for improving tags is appreciated. Could you space that out a little bit? With 3 in 24h there is perhaps no big deal whatsoever to observe. But every edit bumps the post to the top of the questions-tab. if we approach >12 re-tags in a day it seems a bit much for one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, [vexillology](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vexillology) should be for questions on the study of flags (e.g. "When did vexillology become a recognised field of study?", while [flags](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags) would be for the actual flags (e.g. "Why was red chosen in flag x?") Obviously, in practice everyone use both to ask about specific flags only.

I have therefore merged the two flags without making them synonyms. If we do get a question on vexillology the study, we can properly tag it [vexillolgy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vexillolgy), but that tag is destroyed in the meantime.